# SQL Function Help

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I am trying to archive a datagrid into a datatable so I can find it in the table by the archive date. I am using an INSERT SQL statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [VendorArchive] ([Booth], [Deposit], [Rent], [Electric], [Security], 
[AmountPaid], [DatePaid], [PeriodPaid], [TotalDue], [Notes], [ArchiveDate], 
[BalanceDue], GETDATE());

SELECT Booth, Deposit, Rent, Electric, Security AmountPaid, DatePaid, PeriodPaid,  
TotalDue, BalanceDue, Notes
FROM Vendors
```

I then call the sql function in my code inside a button click event:

```
private void vendorArchiveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to archive?", "Perform Archive", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)

            {

                vendorArchiveTableAdapter.PerformArchive();

                MessageBox.Show("Archive has completed.");

            }



        }
```

When i debug and hit the archive button I get this error: "No overload for method 'PerformArchive' takes 0 arguments"

I don't understand. Am I using the wrong SQL statement? Do I need to add all the columns as argumnets in the method call?

Please help.

Comment: How are you doing an insert without values?

Comment: Right click the `PerformArchive` bit of text in the line `vendorArchiveTableAdapter.PerformArchive();` in Visual Studio click "Go to Definition" (or something similar to that) and see what parameters it expects

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski: He is trying to select the values from one table and insert them into another table with a timestamp for when the copy was made.

Comment: Mark Byers is correct. This is exactly what I am trying to accomplish. I guess where I am confused is, when I create a SQL function i.e. PerformArchive, can I not call this function like I would call any other method? Because that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SQL query is wrong but the specific error you get has nothing to do with your SQL query.

Somewhere in your project you have a method called `PerformArchive` and this method takes at least one parameter. You need to provide a value for that parameter.

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, put the cursor on the method name and press F12 to go to the definition and then you can see what the parameters are.

---

Regarding your SQL you need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [VendorArchive] (
    [Booth], [Deposit], [Rent], [Electric], [Security], [AmountPaid], [DatePaid], [PeriodPaid], [TotalDue], [BalanceDue], [Notes], [ArchiveDate]
)
SELECT
    [Booth], [Deposit], [Rent], [Electric], [Security], [AmountPaid], [DatePaid], [PeriodPaid], [TotalDue], [BalanceDue], [Notes], GETDATE()
FROM Vendors
```

Errors that I have fixed:

- Removed extra semicolon.
- Added missing comma between `Security` and `AmountPaid`.
- Fixed the order of columns so that they match in INSERT and SELECT statements.
- Moved GETDATE() to select list instead of insert column list.

Answer (score 0):

Put your cursor on `PerformArchive` and press `F12`.

Look at the methods signature and make sure it matches where you are calling it.